# The first button of GridBagLayout is bigger than other

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a Swing application and I have a big problem with the GridBagLayout.
The program adds dynamically buttons in the scroll pane that is in a BorderLayout, but when I resize the window, the first button gets bigger than others, why?

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 2));
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
    gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0};
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
    panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);
    
    
    int counter=0;
    for(String nomeNazione:nazioni)
    {
        
        btn = new JButton(nomeNazione);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btn = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btn.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc_btn.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btn.gridy = counter;
        gbc_btn.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btn.weighty=1;
        
        
        panel.add(btn, gbc_btn);
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);` Don't guess! Pack once all components are added for the exact right size. 4) `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 2));` 2 pixels tall? *Really?* Also, never set the (preferred or any other) size of a scroll pane. Should be the view port instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are trying to add buttons of the same size to the scroll pane.

The easiest way to do this is to use a panel with a GridLayout.

You then user a wrapper panel so that the height of the buttons are respected when the wrapper panel is added to the scroll pane. Scrollbars will appear as necessary as you add buttons to the panel.

The basic logic would be:

```
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
buttonsPanel.add(...); // loop to add your buttons

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( wrapper );

frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.LINE_START)
```